# Import file dynamically in vue js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, vue.js, vuejs2

Below code which works for me

```
var Index = require('./theme/dir1/index.vue');
```

But I want to use It like this,

```
var path = './theme/'+variable+'/index.vue';
var Index = require(path);
```

Which is not working for me, is there any way to make that fix.,

Comment: @moáois variable is defined before path

Comment: @moáois btw I am using webpack as dependency manager

Comment: This is not import, this is require. Poorly named.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
var Index = require(`./theme/${variable}/index.vue`);
```

Comment: but braces not needed

Comment: which braces, inner or outer ? can u show what u r using ?

Comment: `var Index = require(\`./theme/${variable}/index.vue\`);`